# Algorithm to get all paths in a tree

Tags: c#, algorithms, trees

I have a tree that has n-levels. For example here I have four levels:

[image]

Each node has two children (except for the last one), however everyone except for the first and last node of each row has two parents. I'm trying to figure out a scalable way to get all paths into a List of Lists, so that for this example, I will have a List of Lists of chars:

```
A,B,D,G

A,B,D,H

A,B,E,H
```

etc.

Can anyone help steer me to the right direction of finding an algorithm for this regardless of how many levels?

Comment: As a sketch: perform [depth-first-search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) and keep a list of paths, appending nodes to onto a path as you descend and copying portions of the path on backtracking.

Comment: Strictly speaking, this is not a tree, but a graph. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7423401/whats-the-difference-between-the-data-structure-tree-and-graph and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory). With that in mind, you should find suiting algorithms by searching the web for 'graph traversal algorithms' ;)

Comment: Define "Scalable". The number of such paths is trivially `2^(n-1)` where `n` is the number of levels. Exponential amount of output is not typically called "scalable" or even "usable". What exactly are you trying to do with the paths? It's reasonably trivial to *count* the paths, and convert a path to it's number and back, for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fact that a node can have two parents shouldn't prevent you from using a standard [depth first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search). As you describe it, a child with two parents is still independently part of two "solutions". The fact that there are at most two edges leaving each node simplifies things further.

```
search(node):

    if node is null: // maybe a non-terminal parent's left or right was null
        return  // that or someone gave you a null graph

    add node to "discovered" list

    if node is terminal:
        print the list //[A,B,D,G], [A,B,D,H], etc
        remove node from the list
        return // done at this level

    search(node.left)
    search(node.right)
    remove node from the list // all done at this level
```

You can change the order of discover by going right before you go left.

Comment: I think this led me to the right direction, thanks! I just passed a "discovered" list as a parameter to the recursive function (creating new lists on the node.left and node.right fork) and printed that when it was a terminal node. Didn't have to remove the node from the list though